# Помогите упростить алгоритм преобразования DataTime к int

Tags: c#

Есть нужда произвести с `DataTime.Now` некоторые математические операции потом все привести к строке.

Написал я такой код, но не уверен что он оптимальный:

```
(( UInt64.Parse( DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString()  ) - 36526 ) * 86400).ToString()
```

Может у вас будут идеи как это сделать по проще, меня смущает то что я привожу тип `DataTime`  к `String` потом делаю парсинг к типу `UInt32`, потом опять к типу `String`

Comment: Что ваш код вообще должен делать? У меня он не работает - падает с `FormatException`

Comment: да есть такое дело не понимаю что происходит, сейчас разберусь

Comment: Что именно значат 36526 и 86400 и что вы хотите посчитать?

Comment: Хочу получить временную метку

Comment: а я все понимаю, ваш код смысла не имеет, так как вот это `DateTime.Now.ToString()` скорее всего не выглядит как число и не может быть распарсено как число.

Comment: Ок спасибо! Тогда надо брать как то иначе? Допустим что бы получить количество секунд с 1970?

Comment: попробуйте `DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks`

Comment: Если вам обязательно секунды нужны, то вот https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354893/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-to-the-number-of-seconds-since-1970

Comment: Ошибка закралась из за того что этот код был взят из скрипта работающего в эксель файле а скрипт на VBA и там все ок, и я хотел по той же модели делать временную метку

Comment: еще на тему https://stackoverflow.com/q/17632584/1216425

Comment: В .NET >= 4.6 можно  так `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();`

Comment: Код выглядит ужасно ненормально. В .NET вы должны работать не с числами, а с осмысленными типами.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо, приведите пожалуйста пример как надо делать

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov: Ну вот же вам дали пример: `DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeSeconds();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаю преобразование со временем так

```
        public static int GetUtcSeconds(DateTime date, DateTime startDate = default(DateTime)) {
        if (startDate == DateTime.MinValue) {
            startDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        return (int)date.ToUniversalTime().Subtract(startDate).TotalSeconds;
    }
```

Можно вместо TotalSeconds использовать Ticks